# How to Load Image from the Sub folder?

Tags: c#, html

I am working on C# and html. On view page i want to load images but i am experiencing weird stuff.

when i load image from immediate folder, then it opens .. for example :

```
<img data-u="image" src="~/img/0.Png" />
```

But when i try to load image which is kept in the sub folders then it doesnt open..for example :

```
<img data-u="image" src="~/App_Data/Uploads/1003/Images_1003/1.Png" />
```

Can anybody tell me how to load image from sub folders?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say anything about if your app is Asp.Net or MVC, so I asume it's the former.
In Asp.Net you can use Control.ResolveClientUrl method to get the path relative to the page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am using MVC 5 not Asp.Net